# Probability of drawn ordered random sample of size $r$ by random sampling with replacement being made up of different units

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let $P$ be a population of size $n$. Suppose we draw an ordered random sample of size $r$ by random sampling with replacement. What is the probability that the sample is made up of different units?

**My attempt:**

Let $(n)_r$ samples without replacement and $n^r$ samples with replacement

Then, $$\begin{align}P=\frac{(n)_r}{n^r}&=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1)}{n^r}\\&=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-r+1)}{n^r}\\&=\frac{n^r \left(1- \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1- \frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1- \frac{r+1}{n}\right)}{n^r}\\&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1- \frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{r+1}{n}\right)\end{align}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: So..., your question is?

Comment: what I did, is that ok?

Comment: If I understand it right, then the probability to draw the i-th element is constant $\frac1n$ (with replacement). Then the prob. that the sample is made up of *at least* two different units is $1-\left(\frac1{n}\right)^r$

Comment: @MariaMiel In my opinion, you did it right, except when you made those products in to fractions. You should have $( 1- \frac{r-1}{n})$ in the last term, not  $( 1- \frac{r+1}{n})$

Comment: so it is $r!\, \binom{n}{r} \, / n^r$

Comment: This is the Birthday Problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem